# Apache Lucene Search Phrases in Files

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search

I'm working on a project that has search operation of text files by using Apache Lucene.
The code below works well with a single word. When phrases are searched, it gives the results listed below:

Phrase : ABC DEF

- File1 : Contains "ABC DEF" as phrase
- File2 : Contains "ABC DEF" as phrase
- File3 : Contains ABC and DEF as separate words in different locations
- File4 : Contains ABC and DEF as separate words in different locations
- File5 : Contains ABC
- File6 : Contains DEF

**Results**

File Name - Score

- File1 1.3502092
- File4 1.0447767
- File2 1.0047288
- File3 0.97969353

**Search**

```
public static void search(String keyword, String path) throws IOException, ParseException {

   IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(path)));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

    QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser("contents", analyzer);
    queryParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND);
    Query query = queryParser.parse(keyword);

    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query, 1000);
    ScoreDoc[] document = hits.scoreDocs;
    System.out.println("Total no of hits for content: " + hits.totalHits);

    for (int i = 0; i < document.length; i++) {
        Document doc = searcher.doc(document[i].doc);
        String filePath = doc.get("title");
        System.out.println(filePath + " " + document[i].score);

    }
}
```

As seen on the results,  File4 does not contain phrase but its score higher than File2 that contains phrase. How to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without seeing your files I do not know how to fix your problem. I do think that you should change so the search phrase gets quoted and add some proximity search like `Query query = queryParser.parse("\"" + keyword + "\"~10");`

Answer (score 0):

The fact that file4 matched suggests that you are not searching for the phrase "ABC DEF", but as a term query ABC DEF (without quotes). By default BM25 doesn't take in to account the proximity of the terms. The scoring difference might be because of the length of the document (eg: file4 might be shorter than other docs), term frequency or other factors.

Use a phrase query "ABC DEF" with quotes, so that file4 won't be matched. Add proximity operator "~" to allow a few words between ABC and DEF.

If you are serious about ranking based on proximity, you might want to explore a different similarity model than the default BM25. I'm not sure whether there is a built-in model in Lucene.